# Proof that R (decidable languages) is not closed under homomorphism

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

After searching the internet for a bit, I found that the same proof came up over and over again.
The thing is, it seems like the proof is incomplete. Here's the proof:

> However, the recursive languages are not closed under homomorphism. To see why, consider
> the particular language L consisting of strings of the form (M, w, ci
> ), where M is a coded
> Turing machine with binary input alphabet, w is a binary string, and c is a symbol not
> appearing elsewhere. The string is in L if and only if M accepts w after making at most i
> moves.

> We have defined this particular language to break the closure of recursive language. First
> lest check that indeed L is recursive. Well, yes it is, because to see whether a string is
> in the language, we have to simulate M on w for at most i moves. So you can stop the
> machine after i+1 moves and know for sure you should reject. However, if we apply to L the
> homomorphism that maps the symbols other than c to themselves, and maps c to ε, we find
> that h(L) is the universal language, which we called Lu. We know that Lu is not recursive.
> So in three words, L is recursive, h(L) = Lu is RE but not recursive. So recursive languages
> are not closes under homomorphism.

(Source: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs381/2003fa/asgn12sol/cs381-02-12.pdf)

The last part of the proof states that after mapping L to the homomorphism, h(L) is L_halt, which is not decidable.

My question is, how is h(L) the same as L_halt? It seems that the new language is a language of strings of type (M, w, ci), and a string is in h(L) if and only if M accepts w after making at most 0 moves (because we deleted every c).

(Also, I am pretty sure that h(L) is empty because you can't accept a string after 0 steps, because you can't start the TM with q_accept).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the langauges here $h(\langle M, w, \varepsilon\rangle) \notin L$ certainly, but this does not mean anything releated to $L_{halt}$.

Assume $M$ halts on $w$ after $i$ moves. Then $\langle M, w, c^i \rangle \in L$ and $\langle M, w\rangle \in L_{halt}$. Moreover, $h(\langle M, w, c^i \rangle) = \langle M, w \rangle$.

Otherwise assume $M$ never halts on $w$. Then there does not exist any $i$ s.t. $\langle M, w, c^i \rangle \in L$ and hence, $\langle M, w \rangle \neq h(x)$ for any $x \in L$ (by definition of $h$, these $x$ could only have the form $\langle M, w, c^i\rangle$ for some $i$ to map to $\langle M, w \rangle$).